# Растягивание элементов в TabLayout

Tags: android, material-design

Использую com.android.support:design:22.2.0, но не совсем понятно как делать чтобы размера таба был равен длине текста. Как я понимаю эта либа работает по гайдлайнам гугла в котором показано что нехорошо растягивать табы по ширине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Использую данный проект https://github.com/albinmathew/design-support-library-demo. При добавлении больше 8 табов показывает следующее. Я молчу про квадратную кнопку) Пока не до нее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE); // Вот это добавляем
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы, объясняющие суть.